# Markers move when I make zoom out using ng-map and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, zooming, marker, ng-map

I am using ngmap and angularjs to create markers in google map. All ok, but when I zoom out in the map the markers move.

My Code:

```js
 var app = angular.module('dataview', ['ngMap'])
    app.controller('DataViewCtrl', function($scope, $http)
    {
      $scope.markers=[{lat:30.2817, lng:-81.5273},{lat:30.6824, lng:-81.9680},{lat:31.0004, lng:-82.1580}];

      $scope.mapcenter={lat:$scope.markers[0].lat, lng:$scope.markers[0].lng};
    }
```

```html
<script src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true'></script>
 <script src = '/assets/vendor/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js'></script>
    <map center="{{mapcenter.lat}}, {{mapcenter.lng}}" zoom="5" ng-if="is_map" style="height: 500px;">
        <marker ng-repeat="pos in markers" position="{{pos.lat}}, {{pos.lng}}"></marker>
    </map>
```

Resul OK

[image]

Bad Resul (when zoom out)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I suppose you put the minimum code for the example. In my case, the problem was in SVG images of marker icons. I solved the problem by changing the images by others. Try default icons to test if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A working example of what you are trying to achieve is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/P5Tlui

Note how the markers position is now maintained when you zoom out.

I fixed the issue by assigning the markers' coordinates as following:

```
$scope.markers = [{
    lat: 30.2817,
    lng: -81.5273
  }, {
    lat: 30.6824,
    lng: -81.9680
  }, {
    lat: 31.0004,
    lng: -82.1580
  }];
```

Comment: Not really understand, I see no difference between the way I defined $scope.markers and this. Both are an array of objects of the form {lat, lng}

Comment: What you had was incorrect. You cannot pass in an array of objects to initialise your markers array like that. You use strings or keys within the angular brackets for retrieving items from the array. You need to assign the array as I did. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: you say ($scope.markers =), include the equal sign. Its correct. In my code i use =. it was a mistake when i ask the question.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code in your question. Is this what you have? Does the example I've written work for you? What browser are you using?

Comment: Your example are fine. I do the same and all is ok. My code is executed inside other system. I think that the problem is some include of this parent proyect that affect this function

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare :( The community here might be able to help further if you provide more information in your question e.g. about the parent project and other system.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, In css file I put

canvas{width: 100% !important; height: 360px !important;}

I remove this line and fixed the problem. cavas style to conflict with height defined for map in html